# How can I use an alert or form input to allow a user to set a value of a CSS parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what I want to do is allow a user to type in a value either in an alert on the press of a button, or in a form input field which is used on a button press. The number which has been input needs to be between 0 and 360.

CSS to be changed:

```
.hueshiftFilterEffect{
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg); 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `alert` is not an input method.

Comment: I'm just playing around with filter effects at the moment, I've not done a lot to do with HTML/CSS lately so I haven't tried anything, I've been using jquery for other effects.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: @DannyBarber unfortunately this site isn't for people that haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: if you have been using jQuery for other effects, then you would know what to do ... really ...

Comment: Ah, i didn't realize it want an input method I've been using android more recently.

Comment: I wont place this in a answer. Here is solution with input and button to apply value http://jsfiddle.net/HPdU3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7N8W/2/)

Use the `prompt` function and assign its return value via `element.css()`

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    var w=prompt("Enter new hue:","");
    $('#box').css('-webkit-filter','hue-rotate('+w+'deg)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make change to its style by javascript or a better way is JQuery. You may make a form and override its submit button with a JQuery method and then get a value from the input of the form then set it as an style parameter of your tag.
Is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you part of the way there...you are going to want to work on it it some and add some validation to check that you aren't outside of your degree range.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mDgW/

```
$('.deg').keyup(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  $('.tst').css("-webkit-filter", "hue-rotate("+str+"deg)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prompt should work
Example

```
<button onclick="myAwesomeFunction()">
 Submit CSS
</button>
<script>
function myAwesomeFunction() {
promptVal = prompt("You wanna change the CSS?", "CSS Here");
getElementByClassName("hueshiftFilterEffect").style.whateveryouwanttochangeinstyle = promptVal;
}
</script>
```

Any questions? :D